# Rendering a table with Chart.renderer.text

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Is there  way to render a table in `Highcharts` using `chart.render.text`?

It doesn't seem to be formatting correctly.

```
function(chart) { // on complete

    chart.renderer.text(' <table><th>Browsers</th><tr></tr><tr><td><strong>Total Good</strong></td><td id="total" align="right">900</td></tr><tr><td><strong>Total Bad</strong></td><td id="renew" align="right">450</td></tr></table> ', 150, 80)
        .css({
            color: '#4572A7',
            fontSize: '16px'
        })
        .add();
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2uf8e3xu/13/)

Answer (score 0):

In case when you need print tables, you should do that separately. I mean use renderer.path for lines and renderer.text for labels.

```
    Highcharts.drawTable = function() {

    // user options
    var tableTop = 310,
        colWidth = 100,
        tableLeft = 20,
        rowHeight = 20,
        cellPadding = 2.5,
        valueDecimals = 1,
        valueSuffix = ' °C';

    // internal variables
    var chart = this,
        series = chart.series,
        renderer = chart.renderer,
        cellLeft = tableLeft;

    // draw category labels
    $.each(chart.xAxis[0].categories, function(i, name) {
        renderer.text(
            name, 
            cellLeft + cellPadding, 
            tableTop + (i + 2) * rowHeight - cellPadding
        )
        .css({
            fontWeight: 'bold'
        })       
        .add();
    });

    $.each(series, function(i, serie) {
        cellLeft += colWidth;

        // Apply the cell text
        renderer.text(
                serie.name,
                cellLeft - cellPadding + colWidth, 
                tableTop + rowHeight - cellPadding
            )
            .attr({
                align: 'right'
            })
            .css({
                fontWeight: 'bold'
            })
            .add();

        $.each(serie.data, function(row, point) {

            // Apply the cell text
            renderer.text(
                    Highcharts.numberFormat(point.y, valueDecimals) + valueSuffix, 
                    cellLeft + colWidth - cellPadding, 
                    tableTop + (row + 2) * rowHeight - cellPadding
                )
                .attr({
                    align: 'right'
                })
                .add();

            // horizontal lines
            if (row == 0) {
                Highcharts.tableLine( // top
                    renderer,
                    tableLeft, 
                    tableTop + cellPadding,
                    cellLeft + colWidth, 
                    tableTop + cellPadding
                );
                Highcharts.tableLine( // bottom
                    renderer,
                    tableLeft, 
                    tableTop + (serie.data.length + 1) * rowHeight + cellPadding,
                    cellLeft + colWidth, 
                    tableTop + (serie.data.length + 1) * rowHeight + cellPadding
                );
            }
            // horizontal line
            Highcharts.tableLine(
                renderer,
                tableLeft, 
                tableTop + row * rowHeight + rowHeight + cellPadding,
                cellLeft + colWidth, 
                tableTop + row * rowHeight + rowHeight + cellPadding
            );

        });

        // vertical lines        
        if (i == 0) { // left table border  
            Highcharts.tableLine(
                renderer,
                tableLeft, 
                tableTop + cellPadding,
                tableLeft, 
                tableTop + (serie.data.length + 1) * rowHeight + cellPadding
            );
        }

        Highcharts.tableLine(
            renderer,
            cellLeft, 
            tableTop + cellPadding,
            cellLeft, 
            tableTop + (serie.data.length + 1) * rowHeight + cellPadding
        );

        if (i == series.length - 1) { // right table border    

            Highcharts.tableLine(
                renderer,
                cellLeft + colWidth, 
                tableTop + cellPadding,
                cellLeft + colWidth, 
                tableTop + (serie.data.length + 1) * rowHeight + cellPadding
            );
        }

    });


};

/**
 * Draw a single line in the table
 */
Highcharts.tableLine = function (renderer, x1, y1, x2, y2) {
    renderer.path(['M', x1, y1, 'L', x2, y2])
        .attr({
            'stroke': 'silver',
            'stroke-width': 1
        })
        .add();
}
```

Example:
- http://www.highcharts.com/docs/getting-started/frequently-asked-questions#add-data-table